# IIS 8 factory reset

Tags: application-pool

**How can I roll back to factory settings IIS 8 (8.5) in Windows 8.1??**

I used Web Deploy 3 to import all the server from another computer and after it looked like it brought everything over all application pools crash every time you try to access its websites...

I tried the uninstalling the IIS 8 roll, uninstalling .NET frameworks… then put them back... but the same issue persists.

I believe there has to be some residual configuration that is causing the problem.

So again, how do I roll back the IIS server to a clean state?

Thanks

Comment: Your computer's eventlog should be able to pinpoint the exact cause of the crashes. My first thought would be the user identities those application pools are executing under, they are probably using accounts/sids that are not present on your target computer.

Comment: Did you trying cleaning out the directories that hold the data too? C:\inetpub and C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv

Comment: I cleaned C:\inetpub but not the latest one: C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv... I'll test that and update the post.

Comment: Cleaning the folders above didn't change the fact all application pools stop when you access the websites after a new Installation.
Simon, can you please elaborate more about the user identities?

Answer (score 0):

At the end I had to go back in time 3 days to a previous Restoration Point.
Afterwards add IIS and manually setup and deploy the site.
It worked without issues this time...
**So I won't recommend Web Deploy 3.5 for full site and settings replication.**